# Why std::cout instead of simply cout?

Tags: c++, iostream

I get these error messages for all `cout` and `endl`:

```
main.cc:17:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
main.cc:17:5: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:62:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
```

After following the suggestion, everything is fine. Now I am curious, why I had to do that. We used C++ in classes before, but I never had to write a `std::` before any of those commands. What might be different on this system?

Comment: you have to say you are using std for it to know what cout is. if you do this as an import you can simply say cout, otherwise you have to fully justify it to tell the compiler what cout actuallt is

Comment: Congratulations, you are the 1000000th victim of the stupid habit of importing the `std` namespace that every single introductory course to C++ I've ever seen seems to adopt...

Comment: Sorry Luc, that coding in language <x> is not limited the small group of people who were listening to introductory courses about that language.

Comment: @erikb85 I think his complaint was aimed at people who DID attend the course!

Comment: @LucTouraille why is it bad to use the namespace std??!

Comment: @EdwardBlack It is not bad to use the namespace `std`, on the contrary. It is bad to import all the names it contains (with a `using namespace std` directive) just to avoid typing the `std::` prefix, because this defeats the very purpose of a namespace. (see [this faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). My 3 years old rant was aimed at C++ introductory courses and examples that systematically does that, thereby instiling bad habits in C++ learners.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

It seems possible your class may have been using pre-standard C++.  An easy way to tell, is to look at your old programs and check, do you see:

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
```

The former is pre-standard, and you'll be able to just say `cout` as opposed to `std::cout` without anything additional. You can get the same behavior in standard C++ by adding

```
using std::cout;
```

or

```
using namespace std;
```

Just one idea, anyway.

Comment: Most complete and most readable answer! I even had the <iostream.h> problem!

Comment: Please don't use `using namespace std;`, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 25):

In the C++ standard, `cout` is defined in the `std` namespace, so you need to either say `std::cout` or put

```
using namespace std;
```

in your code in order to get at it.

However, this was not always the case, and in the past `cout` was just in the global namespace (or, later on, in both global and `std`). I would therefore conclude that your classes used an older C++ compiler.

Answer (score 12):

Everything in the Standard Template/Iostream Library resides in namespace std. You've probably used:

```
using namespace std;
```

In your classes, and that's why it worked.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the namespace

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/109029/what-its-the-use-of-using-namespace-std

But you might offend someone

[Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You probably had `using namespace std;` before in your code you did in class. That explicitly tells the precompiler to look for the symbols in `std`, which means you don't need to `std::`. Though it is good practice to `std::cout` instead of `cout` so you explicitly invoke `std::cout` every time. That way if you are using another library that redefines `cout`, you still have the `std::cout` behavior instead of some other custom behavior.

Answer (score 1):

"std" is a namespace used for STL (Standard Template Library). Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace#Use_in_common_languages

You can either write `using namespace std;` before using any stl functions, variables or just insert `std::` before them.

Comment: Pedantic, perhaps:  It's actually the C++ Standard Library elements, not just the STL, that are in namespace `std`.  Reference C++03:17.4.1.1/2: "All [C++ Standard] library entities except macros, operator new and operator delete are defined within the
namespace std or namespaces nested within namespace std."

Answer (score -4):

If you are working in ROOT, you do not even have to write `#include<iostream>` and `using namespace std;` simply start from `int filename()`.

This will solve the issue.