# Is there a way to reference cout without using namespace std or prefixing with std::?

Tags: c++, cout

I'm pretty new to C++, and I'm using `std::cout` for debugging purposes.

Though, I'd really like to be able to just use `cout` rather than the whole `std::cout` thing. I know i could import the `std` namespace, but  I've been explained it was a bad thing due to name clashing that can occur because of this.

Is there anyway to do this?

I tried

`std::ostream cout = std::cout;`

But I get

`function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> &) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (declared at line 391 of "/usr/include/c++/5/ostream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`

Please suggest.

Comment: Prefer the use of `std::cout`.

Comment: Pardon me, but why?

Comment: Because it is the best practice in C++ and introducing the entire `std` namespace is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Yes but I actually wanted just to introduce some elements of the namespace (`cout`, `endl`, that kind of things), as I stated in my post.

Comment: @Ron What is considered a bad practice is unscoped `using` declarations. Having  `using std;` or `using std::cout;` inside a function or a block in general does not have anything bad. And depending on the case, some may argue that even unscoped `using` is fine in a `.cc`/`.cpp` file, since it does not affect other compilation units (although I do prefer to avoid that too personally).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure, with a [using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

```
using std::cout;
```

Usual health warnings about not doing this in header files, and limiting it to small scopes apply.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Also, what would be the recommended way to "import" the `ostream` type? Should I rather use a `typedef std::ostream ostream` or rather `using std::ostream`?

Comment: @ThomasKowalski You can't "import" things in C++, at least not yet. What you need to do is include the appropriate header. I would probably use the using declaration as shown above, but only in an implementation file, and in a limited scope. But in general, I just write `std::` most of the time.

Comment: @ThomasKowalski: Might be useful to mention `#include <iosfwd>` here. If you jus need the `std::ostream` declaration, you don't need all of `<ostream>`

Answer (score 7):

You can't copy streams (think about it, it just doesn't make sense), but you can get a reference to them:

```
std::ostream& my_cout = std::cout;
```

However, I would strongly advice you not to do so. If you see in some code `std::cout` you can be almost 100% certain that you know what it is. On the other hand a `cout` alone you should already look suspicious to you and a `my_cout` could really be anything. I know it is hard, but get used to type `std::`, on the long run it will help you more than you need time to type those 5 letters.

Answer (score 4):

Your way would be:

```
auto& cout = std::cout;
```

but you might simply do

```
using std::cout;
```

(with similar restriction than using namespace: not in namespace scope in header, ideally limiting the scope of using directive as much as possible)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, too low rating to comment, but why don't you just type

```
using std::cout;
```

at the top of the file and then just use `cout`.
P.S. also answered at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950083/why-stdcout-instead-of-simply-cout)

Comment: irrespective your rep, this should be an answer not a comment. Asnwering in comments is tempting, but it bypasses reviews and votes, which are essential to make SO work

Answer (score 0):

One way is [using-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration), which introduces only `std::cout` instead of all names in `std::`:

```
using std::cout;
```

The way you tried won't work - it's an attempt to copy `std::cout` to another object - and `std::cout` is not copyable.

Alternative is to use a reference:

```
std::ostream& cout = std::cout;
```

Now, `cout` points to `std::cout` instead of being its copy.

The second way can be useful, if you want to, for example, write a function without deciding whether it should output to `cout`, file or something else:

```
void func(std::ostream& output) {
    output << "works with cout, files, etc.";
}
```

Comment: minor nitpick: `cout` doesnt really "point" to `std::cout`. imho it is more correct to say `cout` **is** `std::cout`, because a reference is just an alias

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to abbreviate `std::cout`, it could be that what you are really looking for is dependency injection.

Remember that `std::cout` is a reference to a model of a `std::ostream`.

We can use that in our favour to make code more re-usable, testable and loosely coupled.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::ostream& do_something(std::ostream& os)
{
    os << "Hello, World!\n";
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    // inject std::cout
    do_something(std::cout);

    // inject a stringstream
    std::ostringstream ss;
    do_something(ss);
    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```